# How to change a UILabel through a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uipopovercontroller

I have a simple code, where it has been two classes: **ViewController** (which is the main rootViewController) and **ProductsViewController** (who is a Controller that opens through a PopoverController).

What is happening is the following, within the **ViewController** class I have a setter command that is responsible for updating the UILabel:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property(nonatomic,retain)  NSString *saver;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLabel.text = saver;
}
-(void)setLabel:(NSString*)value{
    saver = value;
    myLabel.text = value;
}
```

In **ProductsViewController** Class I have the code which is responsible for activating the setter method:

```
ViewController *detailViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[detailViewController setLabel:@"Changes?"];
[detailViewController release];
```

I believe the problem is the time when the popover is open, because I believe that somehow the UILabel is inactive, since if we put  `NSLog(@"Exists -> %@",myLabel);` inside the setter method, we get **(null)**

Could someone help me solve this problem, and how to get around this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried to work with protocols that way:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ProductsViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ProductsViewControllerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}

-(IBAction)showPopOver:(id)sender;
- (void)productWasSelected:(NSString *)product;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)presentProductsViewController:(ProductsViewController *)productsViewController {
    productsViewController.delegate = self;
    //present in popover here...
}

- (void)productWasSelected:(NSString *)product{
    myLabel.text = product;
}
```

**ProductsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ProductsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)productWasSelected:(NSString *)product;
@end

@interface ProductsViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ProductsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**ProductsViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate productWasSelected:@"Selected Product"];
    NSLog(@"Called!");
}
```

My ShowPopover Method is below:

```
-(IBAction)showPopOver:(id)sender{

    UIButton *btn =sender;
    ProductsViewController *productsView =[[ProductsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductsViewController" bundle:nil];
    popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:productsView];
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    [productsView release];

}
```

Comment: What do you think `[[ViewController alloc] init]` does?

Comment: @CrimsonChris Oh I get now, Makes sense now, I tried to take the [[ViewController alloc] init], but I received the error that the variable has not been initialized...

Comment: `[[ViewController alloc] init]` gives you a NEW object, not a reference to your old one.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I Update my Code see now...and plz help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two objects that share the same class DO NOT make them the same object. You probably want to use delegation here. There are plenty of tutorials online. Here's an example...

```
@protocol ProductsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)productWasSelected:(NSString *)product;
@end

@interface ProductsViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ProductsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end


@implementation ProductsViewController

- (void)didSelectProduct {
    [self.delegate productWasSelected:@"Selected Product"];
}

@end
```

---

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ProductsViewControllerDelegate>
@end


@implementation MainViewController

- (IBAction)showPopOver:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn =sender;
    ProductsViewController *productsView =[[ProductsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductsViewController" bundle:nil];
    productsView.delegate = self;
    popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:productsView];
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}

- (void)productWasSelected:(NSString *)product {
    self.myLabel.text = product;
}

@end
```

Comment: I try this in my code exactly as you put it, gave a parsed and seems to have a certain logic, but my UILabel not changed even when the popover closed

Comment: No, please add your new code to the bottom of your question. Future readers will want to see how your problem was resolved.

Comment: You are not using `presentProductsViewController`. That's your problem. You need to set the delegate on your ProductViewController to be your MainViewController.

Comment: Sorry but is difficult to me to understand this, I`m noob, Can you give me a website with this example..So I can see it in practice?

Comment: You need to be setting the delegate inside your `(IBAction)showPopOver:(id)sender`method.

Comment: I need your help, I stay with this problem in 3 weeks, and I doesn't solve... This is very difficult to me..

Comment: I've updated my answer using your popover method. By the way, you should really be using ARC. It's easier than manually managing your memory.

Comment: Man I can`t believe this works :D, Thanks very much, now I will study your code and save in my examples, Much thanks for you!

Answer (score 2):

You are totally lost and confused. Your code creates a new instance of a view controller, invokes a setter method on that new view controller, and then releases the view controller.

This is like having a notebook that you keep in your pocket to keep notes.

You go to the store, buy a new notebook (alloc/init), write a note in that new notebook, throw the notebook away (release), and then wonder why the note you wrote isn't in the notebook in your pocket.

Other things:

Don't use a method named setSomething unless it is a property setter. That is the naming convention for the setter for a property called "something", and that naming convention is enforced by the language.

You declared a method setlabel, but the code is calling a method setLabel. Different capitalization = different methods in C and C-like languages like Objective C.

When your "setLabel" method is called, the label may not exist yet.

I suggest that you create a string property, labelString.

Set that property in your ProductsViewController instance **once you sort out how to get a pointer to the ProductsViewController that you are going to display**. Then in your ProductsViewController's viewWillAppear method, copy the value of labelString to the label.

Post the code that sets up and displays the ProductsViewController and we can help show you how to set properties on that actual view controller instead of one that you create and then immediately throw away.

Comment: This seems to be a common misconception among new iOS developers. Perhaps it has more to do with being new to OOP in general.

Comment: Ok, your new code creates a ProductsViewController and installs it in a popover, but now you're not setting the value that you want to pass to the popover. What happened to that bit? And note my comments about waiting until viewWillAppear to copy the value into the view controller's views.